# Flash Builder:How to sort spark datagrid column when user clicks header?

Tags: datagrid, flash-builder

I am trying to sort a spark datagrid column when users click the header of individual column. I have searched google but haven't found any good tutorials. I would appreciate if anyone here can help me out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `sortableColumns` to `true`? Cause actually it should work right out of the box if that property is set.

Comment: Ty Ak_Birdy but the datagrid it still not sortable after I add sortableColumns property. Any other thoughts?  +1 though

Comment: That is odd. Check out this tutorial on adobe.com and report back if that doesn't work for you. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc3647f39ab2512d530e9965-8000.html